# EXCEL - Using Multiple IF Statements

Tags: excel

I need help with modifying an Excel formula.

**Here is my current formula:**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D9), IF(ISBLANK(E9),"","input Up_Lw"), IF(ISBLANK(E9),"input Up_Up",SUM(E9-D9)))
```

**What I would like to add to the formula above:**

IF G9="FAIL", H10 will be blank

[Snip of Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHqOY.png)

Comment: What cell is the formula in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the formula is in `H10`, you can use:

```
=IF(G9="FAIL","", IF(ISBLANK(D9), IF(ISBLANK(E9),"","input Up_Lw"), IF(ISBLANK(E9),"input Up_Up",SUM(E9-D9))))
```

If the formula is in some other cell, it cannot be done with a single formula.

Comment: Hi Ron,  I knew I forgot to add some critical info. The formula is for H10. I inputted your suggestion and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help.